# How to automatically Load this Ajax Sliding Panel on Body Onload event?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

```
Js Code:jquery.slidepanel.js

;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    var defaults = {
        orientation: 'left',
        mode: 'push',
        static: false
    };

    // The actual plugin constructor
    function Slidepanel( $element, options ) {
        this.$element = $element;
        this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options) ;
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this.init();
    }

    Slidepanel.prototype.init = function () {

        var base = this;

        if($('#slidepanel').length == 0){
            var panel_html = '<div id="slidepanel" class="cb_slide_panel"><div class="wrapper"><a href="#" class="close">Close</a><div class="inner"><div class="wrapper"></div></div></div></div>';
            $(panel_html).hide().appendTo($('body'));    
        }

        this.$panel = $('#slidepanel');
        this.$body = $('body');
        this.$body_position = this.$body.css('position');

        //hide the panel and set orientation class for display
        this.$panel.hide().addClass('panel_' + this.options.orientation);

        //set current trigger link to false for the current panel
        this.$panel.data('slidepanel-current', false);
        this.$panel.data('slidepanel-loaded', false);


        //reset any defined a positions
        this.$panel.css('left', '').css('right', '').css('top', '').css('bottom', '');

        //set a default top value for left and right orientations
        //and set the starting position based on element width
        if(this.options.orientation == 'left' || this.options.orientation == 'right') {
            var options = {};
            options['top'] = 0;
            options[this.options.orientation] = -this.$panel.width();
            this.$panel.css(options);
        }

        //set a default left value for top and bottom orientations
        //and set the starting position based on element height
        if(this.options.orientation == 'top' || this.options.orientation == 'bottom') {
            var options = {};
            options['left'] = 0;
            options[this.options.orientation] = -this.$panel.height();
            this.$panel.css(options);
        }

        //bind click event to trigger ajax load of html content
        //and panel display to any elements that have the attribute rel="panel"
        $(this.$element).on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            //if the request mode is static
            if(base.options.static) { 
                //show the panel
                base.expand();
            }
            // if the reques mode is ajax 
            else {
                //load the external html
                base.load();
            };
        });

        //listen for a click on the close buttons for this panel
        $('.close', this.$panel).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            base.collapse();
        });

    };

    Slidepanel.prototype.load = function() {
            var base = this;
            //if the current trigger element is the element that just triggered a load
            if(this.$panel.data('slidepanel-current') == this.$element) {
                //collapse the current panel
                this.collapse();
                return;
            } else {
                //show the slide panel
                this.expand();
                //get the target url
                var href = $(this.$element).attr('href');

                //prevent an ajax request if the current URL is the the target URL
                if(this.$panel.data('slidepanel-loaded') !== href){
                    //load the content from the target url, and update the panel html
                    $('.inner .wrapper', this.$panel).html('').load(href, function() {
                        //remove the loading indicator
                        base.$panel.removeClass('loading');
                        //set the current loaded URL to the target URL
                        base.$panel.data('slidepanel-loaded', href);
                    });
                //  the current URL is already loaded
                } else {
                    //remove the loading indicator
                    this.$panel.removeClass('loading');
                }
            }
            //set the current source element to this element that triggered the load
            this.$panel.data('slidepanel-current', this.$element);
    };


    Slidepanel.prototype.expand = function() {
        var base = this;
                //set the css properties to animatate

        var panel_options = {};
        var body_options = {};
        panel_options.visible = 'show';
        panel_options[this.options.orientation] = 0;
        body_options[this.options.orientation] = (this.options.orientation == 'top' || this.options.orientation == 'bottom') ? this.$panel.height() : this.$panel.width();

        //if the animation mode is set to push, we move the body in relation to the panel
        //else the panel is overlayed on top of the body
        if(this.options.mode == 'push'){
            //animate the body position in relation to the panel dimensions
            this.$body.css('position', 'absolute').animate(body_options, 250);
        }

        //animate the panel into view
        this.$panel.addClass('loading').animate(panel_options, 250, function() {
            //show the panel's close button
            $('.close', base.$panel).fadeIn(250);
        });
    };

    Slidepanel.prototype.collapse = function() {
        //hide the close button for this panel
        $('.close', this.$panel).hide();

        //set the css properties to animatate
        var panel_options = {};
        var body_options = {};
        panel_options.visible = 'hide';
        panel_options[this.options.orientation] = -(this.$panel.width() + 40);
        body_options[this.options.orientation] = 0;

        //if the animation mode is push, move the document body back to it's original position
        if(this.options.mode == 'push'){
            this.$body.css('position', this.$body_position).animate(body_options, 250);
        }
        //animate the panel out of view
        this.$panel.animate(panel_options, 250).data('slidepanel-current', false);
    };

    $.fn['slidepanel'] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_slidepanel')) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_slidepanel', new Slidepanel( this, options ));
            }
        });
    }

})(jQuery, window);

Css Code: jquery.slidepanel.css

/* Slide Panel */
        .cb_slide_panel {
            background:#383838;
            border-right: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 23px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17), -1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85) inset;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 65000;
            display: block;
        }
        .cb_slide_panel.panel_left, .cb_slide_panel.panel_right {
            width: 278px;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .cb_slide_panel.panel_right {
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 23px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17), 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85) inset;
        }
        .cb_slide_panel.panel_top, .cb_slide_panel.panel_bottom {
            height: 300px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .cb_slide_panel.panel_top {
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 23px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17), -1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85) inset;
        }
        .cb_slide_panel.panel_bottom {
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 23px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17), 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85) inset;
        }
        .cb_slide_panel a.close {
            background: #383838;
            border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
            height: 40px;
            position: absolute;
            text-indent: -9999em;
            width: 40px;
            display: block;
        }
        .cb_slide_panel.panel_left a.close {
            right: -42px;
            top: 20px;
        }
        .cb_slide_panel.panel_right a.close {
            left: -42px;
            top: 20px;
        }
        .cb_slide_panel.panel_top a.close {
            bottom: -41px;
            left: 20px;
        }
        .cb_slide_panel.panel_bottom a.close {
            top: -41px;
            left: 20px;
        }
        .cb_slide_panel a.close:hover {
            background-position: -40px 0;
        }

        .cb_slide_panel .inner { /*-- For inner body -- */
            padding: 0px 0 0 0px;
            width: 248px;
        }
        .cb_slide_panel.loading .inner {
            min-height: 300px;
            background: url(../images/ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat scroll 50% 50% transparent
        }
        .cb_slide_panel h1 {
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            margin: -0.15em 0 20px;
            text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000000;
        }
        .cb_slide_panel h2 {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #276BB3;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-size: 14px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 1px 0 0;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #1F5287;
        }
        .cb_slide_panel ul {
            padding: 0 0 0 10px;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        .cb_slide_panel ul li {
        }
        .cb_slide_panel ul li a {
            color: #91aac4;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .cb_slide_panel ul li a:hover {
            color: #fff;
        }

PHP Page: External.php

<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='css/PanelSlide/jquery.slidepanel.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
</head>
<body>

<?php
                include('config.php');
                $userid= $_SESSION['SESS_ID'];
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user where identificationcode ='09-13906'");

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                  {
                echo "<div id='container' style='background:url(http://wallpoper.com/images/00/42/74/22/textures-backgrounds_00427422.jpg);background-size:100% 200%; border:0px solid silver;width:100%;height:300px;margin:0px;' class='cb_slide_panel'>";

                    echo "<p style='margin-left:10px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:10px;'>Welcome back, " .$row['name']. "</font><a href='external.html' data-slidepanel='panel' style='float:right;margin-right:10px;text-decoration:none;'>Edit Profile</a></p>";
                    echo "<img src=".$row['image']." width='200px' height='200px' style='border:2px solid gray; margin-left:20px;'>";

                echo "</div>";

                  }

?> 

</body>
</html>

And The Main Page where to apply the slide and call external.php

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>IFSU-CMS My Uploads</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<!-- For the Slide panel -->
<!--Include jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Include the slidepanel plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/PanelSlide/jquery.slidepanel.js"></script>
<!--Add the css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/PanelSlide/jquery.slidepanel.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('[data-slidepanel]').slidepanel(
          {
              orientation: 'top',
              mode: 'push'
          }
          );
      });
</script>


<!-- End of the Slide panel -->
</head>
<body>

<a href='external.php' data-slidepanel='panel' style='float:right;margin-right:10px;text-decoration:none;'>View Profile</a>


</body>
</html>
```

**Please Help me to automatical load the panel everytime the Main page is loaded.**

I got this plugin on this link...Please see if my presentation is messy and unclear. http://codebomber.com/jquery/slidepanel/#install

Comment: You want to define document inside your module `(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {` but you actually made it `undefined` by your call `})(jQuery, window);` ; I am not sure it causes an issue, but still.

Comment: I don't understand @Nathan P ..I'm not familiar to AJAX or JQUERY...Can't I just have a better or easier way to call it through Functions? , Cause i noticed the event / command only applies onClick event just like when clicking the View Profile link...

Comment: Problem is your code is too long to be reviewed, can't you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or simplify it ?